# Google Script для экспорта в txt

Tags: google-spreadsheet, google-apps-script

Есть таблица 
[image]
Задача: экспортировать через(начиная с 1) столбец (начиная с 3 строки) в файл txt(название брать с первой строки). Для этого я написал скрипт

```
function export() {
  var Folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("ID");
  var SpreadSheets = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ID').getSheetByName('Минуса');
  var values = SpreadSheets.getRange("A3:A").getValues();
  var txtName = SpreadSheets.getRange("A1").getValues();
  var text = values.map(function (a) {return a.join('\t');}).join('\r\n');
  var Files = Folder.getFiles();
  while(Files.hasNext()){
  var File = Files.next();
    if(File.getName() === txtName + ".txt"){
      Folder.removeFile(File);
    }
    }
  Folder.createFile(txtName + '.txt', text);
```

Проблема возникает если столбцов становится очень много(скрипт становится очень длинным) и я попытался написать в виде цикла

```
function export() {
  var Folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("ID");
  var Files = Folder.getFiles();
  var SpreadSheets = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ID').getSheetByName('Минуса');
  var lastRow = SpreadSheets.getLastRow();
  var c =1;
  for(var i = 3; i<=lastRow;i++){
    for(;c<=15;c+2){
    var values = SpreadSheets.getRange(i, c).getValue();
    var text = values.map(function (a) {return a.join('\t');}).join('\r\n');}
      for(;c>15;c+2){var txtName = SpreadSheets.getRange(1, c).getValues();}
     while(Files.hasNext()){
  var File = Files.next();
    if(File.getName() === txtName + ".txt"){
      Folder.removeFile(File);}
     }
    Folder.createFile(txtName + '.txt', text);
    }
   }
```

Пишет

> TypeError: Не удается обнаружить функцию map в объекте авамис

Помогите, пожалуйста, правильно написать этот скрипт.

Comment: https://toster.ru/q/503585#answer_1173902

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ругается правильно, потому как Вы вызываете метод [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)() не у массива, а у строки:

```
var values = SpreadSheets.getRange(i, c).getValue();
```

Этот метод [getValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValue())  возвращает объект следующих типов, в зависимости от типа данных в ячейке:

> The value may be of type Number, Boolean, Date, or String depending on the value of the cell.

Если по заданию, то попробуйте такой скрипт:

```
function export2(){
  //Если скрипт привязан к таблице
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  //Если скрипт не привязан к таблице:
  // var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SS ID")
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("SHEET NAME")
  var arrData = sheet.getDataRange().getValues()
  var arrNames = []
  var arrTexts = []
  // Проходим по всем данным и составляем 2 массива с именами файлов и текстом (для каждого ВТОРОГО)
  //for(var col = 1; col < arrData[0].length; col+=2){
  // для 1,3,5 итд столбцы
  for(var col = 0; col < arrData[0].length; col+=2){
    var fileName = arrData[0][col] + ".txt"
    var arrText = []
    for(var row = 2; row < arrData.length; row++){
      if(arrData[row][col]){
        arrText.push(arrData[row][col])
      }
    }
    arrNames.push(fileName + ".txt")
    arrTexts.push(arrText.join("\r\n"))
  }
  // Удаляем все существующие файлы с такими же названиями, как у нас (как в Вашем примере)
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("F ID")
  var files = folder.getFiles()
  while(files.hasNext()){
    var file = files.next();
    if(arrNames.indexOf(file.getName() != -1)){
      folder.removeFile(file)
    }
  }
  // Создаем файлы
  for(var i = 0; i < arrNames.length; i++){
    folder.createFile(arrNames[i], arrTexts[i])
  }
}
```

P.S. Я думаю, данный скрипт можно еще как-то оптимизировать, улучшить и т.д., дерзайте!

Comment: Скрипт не работает. он создает пустые файлы с названием .txt(если проставить ";" то просто создает 4 файла "." "t" "x" "t")

Comment: А покажите Ваш файл источник? Скорее всего, проблема в том, что Вы указали, что необходимо экспортировать каждый ВТОРОЙ столбец, а на самом деле, судя по скриншоту, это 1, 3, 5 итд

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1afQft7V3l38vB37KeGDSM9hcEmyz2nui6spTW9HSiF8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Просто var col = 1 меняем на var col =0. Подправил ответ

Comment: Я так и сделал название он не правильно ставит. Но большое спасибо теперь есть с чем работать

Comment: Так, а почему не работает? Я накатал простой пример с 10 столбцами - все правильно создает 5 файлов. Что именно не работает?

Comment: Я проверил все файлы не работает только var fileName = arrData[0][col] + ".txt" http://prntscr.com/ibv6tn в отмеченных написано undefined но все столбцы экспортированы

Comment: http://prntscr.com/ibv7nw сделал изменение а то .txt не проставлялось

Comment: исправил ответ.

Comment: Удалил все и заново вставил ваш скрипт все заработало. Большое спасибо за помощь